# SQL Server : drop schema with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got an old schema that needs to be removed. Problem is it's got the special character `\` in the name (believe me I'm no fan of special characters in schema names). I have tried commands like the following

```
DROP SCHEMA databasename."COMPANY\user1"
```

where `COMPANY\user1` is the name of the schema.

However, I end up getting errors like the following

> SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near '.'.`

I've dropped all of the tables inside of the schema, so I don't think there should be any objects remaining. I had success dropping tables with the following command

```
DROP TABLE databasename."COMPANY\user1".persontable;
```

Any idea why my attempt to drop the schema is failing? I'm sure it's something obvious I'm missing in the syntax.

Comment: Can't test it right now, but don't you have to _use_ the database 1st and then drop the schema? As in `use databasename;drop schema [COMPANY\user1]`...

Comment: @ssarabando you were right, I wasn't selecting the database correctly. See my comment on Gordon Linooff's answer. I am surprised that the SQL you posted didn't work. I'm sure some iteration of it would have.

Comment: probably some quirk in your client. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using square braces?

```
drop schema databasename.[COMPANY\user1]
```

Actually, this doesn't work, because `drop schema` doesn't accept the database (as sort of implied by the syntax [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186751.aspx)).  Just go into the database and do:

```
drop schema [COMPANY\user1]
```

This works for me with names that have unusual characters.

Comment: Going inside the database did the trick! Using the Oracle SQLDeveloper 2 tool you do this by right clicking the db and selecting "select default database" option.